# Problem creating type with Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit

I got a following base class:

```
public class ValidationItem 
{
    public ObservableCollection<object> GetFilteredValues( ObservableCollection<object> values)
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<object>(); // nothing here yet
    }
```

}

I create a type which inherits this base type and I create a getter which is going to return a base class GetFilteredValues method result.

This is how a new property should look like:

```
public ObservableCollection<object> Values
{
    get { return GetFilteredValues(_values); }
    set { _values = value; }
}
```

This is what I do:

```
Type pType = typeof(ObservableCollection<object>);

FieldBuilder fieldBuilder = tb.DefineField("_" + propertyName, pType, FieldAttributes.Private);

PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = tb.DefineProperty( propertyName, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, pType, null);

MethodBuilder getPropMthdBldr = tb.DefineMethod("get_" + propertyName,
                                MethodAttributes.Public |
                                MethodAttributes.SpecialName |
                                MethodAttributes.HideBySig,
                                pType, Type.EmptyTypes);
getPropMthdBldr.SetReturnType(typeof(ObservableCollection<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(object)));
ILGenerator getIL = getPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();

MethodInfo minfo = typeof(ValidationItem).GetMethod("GetFilteredValues", new[] { typeof(ObservableCollection<object>) }); // it's not null so everything is ok here

getIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
getIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
getIL.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, minfo, Type.EmptyTypes);
getIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getPropMthdBldr);
```

But each time I run an app and use this created type, I get an error "Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program". What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried writing the `DynamicAssembly` to disk and running it through peverify? peverify normally gives good error messages.

Comment: Is your main goal to create an instance of this concrete type using reflection or actually create THE type during runtime?

Comment: 2Tim: I cannot save assembly because I use Silverlight.
2Wallace: Yes I must create an instance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `GetFilteredValues`, the only thing on the stack is the `ObservableCollection<object>`.  Since `GetFilteredValues` is an instance method, you also need to push `this`.  Add a second `Ldarg_0` before the existing one so that you push it on the stack before `_values`:

```
getIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
getIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
getIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
getIL.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, minfo, Type.EmptyTypes);
getIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Answer (score 3):

As per documentation to [Ldfld](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldfld.aspx), stack transition is the following

1. An object reference (or pointer) is pushed onto the stack.
2. The object reference (or pointer) is popped from the stack; the value of the specified field in the object is found.
3. The value stored in the field is pushed onto the stack.

So after executing

```
getIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
getIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
```

you will have only field reference on the evaluation stack (without 'this'). To fix, duplicate arg_0

```
getIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
getIL.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
getIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
getIL.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, minfo, Type.EmptyTypes);
getIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

This should help.